# Can there be 2 Debezium connector running in one Kafka cluster?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, debezium, debezium-engine

[image]
From [Debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/architecture.html) official page, there's this picture showing that multiple Debezium connector can connect to the same Kafka.

So I have 2 databases, 2 Debeziums, 1 Kafka running in docker-compose, but it seems like only 1 debezium sent update to kafka (watch from kafdrop).

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:

  hero_db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    expose:
      - '5432'
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ]
    volumes:
      - hero_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  villian_db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
    ports:
      - '2345:2345'
    expose:
      - '2345'
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ]
    volumes:
      - villian_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    container_name: kafdrop
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:9092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -noverify"
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  hero_debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:1.9
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    expose:
      - '8083'
    environment:
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: hero_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: hero_offsets
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: hero_statuses
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
    depends_on: [ zookeeper, kafka, hero_db ]

  villian_debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:1.9
    ports:
      - 8084:8083
    expose:
      - '8084'
    environment:
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: villian_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: villian_offsets
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: villian_statuses
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
    depends_on: [ zookeeper, kafka, villian_db ]

volumes:
  hero_db_data:
  villian_db_data:
```

Here's a debezium config file in json of hero_dbz and villian_dbz:
hero_dbz.json

```
{
    "name": "hero-postgresql-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "database.hostname": "hero_db",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgrespassword",
        "database.dbname": "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "hero_server",
        "table.include.list": "public.heroes",
        "table.whitelist": "public.heroes",
        "topic.prefix": "topic_heroes"
    }
}
```

villian_dbz.json

```
{
    "name": "villian-postgresql-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "database.hostname": "villian_db",
        "database.port": "2345",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgrespassword",
        "database.dbname": "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "villian_server",
        "table.include.list": "public.villians",
        "table.whitelist": "public.villians",
        "topic.prefix": "topic_villian"
    }
}
```

I config both hero_dbz & villian_dbz with these command:
`curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 127.0.0.1:8083/connectors/ --data "@hero_dbz.json"`
`curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 127.0.0.1:8084/connectors/ --data "@villian_dbz.json"`

Here's a screen from Kafdrop showing only data from hero_db (hero_server.public.heroes) but nothing from villian_db.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem running multiple kafka-connect servers. There might an issue in your configuration and setup. Perhaps look into to logs of the villian connector.

your internal port of villan db is wrong IMHO:

```
villian_db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
    ports:
      - '2345:5432'
    expose:
      - '2345'
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ]
    volumes:
      - villian_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

updates:

please add different `GROUP_ID`s env to the connect clusters. background:

> This environment variable is required when running the Kafka Connect service. Set this to an ID that uniquely identifies the Kafka Connect cluster the service and its workers belong to.

Something like `GROUP_ID: 3` and `GROUP_ID: 2` for the other. Your json should point to `5432`, internal port of PostgresDB, so the .json files should point to `5432` (both)

And Your Zookeeper is wrongly configures, please fix it like that:

```
....
ports:
      - 2181:2181
```

Comment: I showed the error I saw from villian_dbz in the answer post, could you please help me check it. Thank you in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565906/20120256

Comment: Thank you for the answer! so the problem is that I hadn't added `GROUP_ID: n` for each Debezium.

Answer (score 0):

After I fixed my villians_db to run on port 2345. Then connect both of hero and villian debezium to Kafka via their JSON file.
Inside the villian_dbz it keep showing this message :

```
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,210 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Rebalance started   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,210 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] (Re-)joining group   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,211 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=6, memberId='connect-1-a2647c32-4c10-48be-b832-a38a37a11cd0', protocol='sessioned'}   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,211 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=6, memberId='connect-1-a2647c32-4c10-48be-b832-a38a37a11cd0', protocol='sessioned'}   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,211 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Joined group at generation 6 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-07842920-d640-4c15-ae17-ad4900077143', leaderUrl='http://172.19.0.8:8083/', offset=5, connectorIds=[hero-postgresql-connector], taskIds=[], revokedConnectorIds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,211 WARN   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Catching up to assignment's config offset.   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,211 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Current config state offset -1 is behind group assignment 5, reading to end of config log   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,212 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: -1   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
2023-02-25 20:43:15 2023-02-25 13:43:15,212 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Current config state offset -1 does not match group assignment 5. Forcing rebalance.   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
```

This error does not appear if only one (either hero or villian) dbz connect to Kafka.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please have look.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, should this be a comment or perhaps an edit to the question?